# Flutter - How to read a 500MB text file from assets (No JSON)

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a 500 MB text file in my assets folder. I want to read the content of this file (if possible line by line).
When I use "loadString()", just a couple of lines my file are printed (5 from 4000 lines). How can I read the whole content of the file?
Here is my code:

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class ReadText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<void> loadAsset() async {
      var myFileContent = 
                      rootBundle.loadString('res/assets/raw/mydata.csv');

      //Printing
      return myFileContent.then(print);
    }

    loadAsset();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Read File"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new Text("Empty page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to print the content of your file?

Comment: First I am printing to the console. It is simply to see if it works. I will use the content later in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print a large string in Console using the print() function. Which is not possible, flutter has its limit for large values to be printed in the console

You can try

```
debugPrint()
```

Function, but this too doesn’t guarantee whether your whole string (file) will be printed in the console.
I’ll recommend you to print it on some Text widget to see it. 
I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. With debugPrint() I see everything. 
Do you know how I could read the file line by line?

Comment: To read the file line by line, I guess you need to use regex pattern and check for escape sequence ‘\n’ as it indicates the end of the line. Please accept this answer as correct answer if this solved what you asked.

Comment: it helped me to find the solution.
I have found a way to read my file using "readAsLinesSync"